# Force form to open in focus/on top

Tags: c#, forms, desktop-application

I have a class library that opens 2 forms: The first is a splash screen that shows a loading message while the assemblies are loaded. The second shows a form with some controls on it. My problem is, my class library is invoked through a web applet and JNI. My forms always show behind the browser page.

I know I have a few different options, but what is the best way to make sure my forms open in front when they are first opened? I don't want them to stay on top forever. `Focus` and `BringToFront` don't seem to be working.

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Focus();
    this.BringToFront();
}
```

`Activate()` doesn't work either...

Comment: `Activate` should work, if you call it at the right time.  That time is not in the constructor.  You must call it after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track, but put it in the form's Shown() event:

```
public void MyForm_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Activate();
}
```

This will ensure that the form is actually visible and constructed when you ask it to step forward.

Comment: I put this in my `Shown` event, and the event is getting called correctly, but it's still showing behind my browser.

Comment: Anything more going on post-launch that could be re-focusing the browser?

Comment: No, nothing is happening after the call to my Java applet that would re-focus the browser. I am thinking I might need to do something in Java since a Java thread is actually running my code? If I have the Java console in focus when the form is launched, it works as I want it to...

Comment: I had to include `BringToFront()` after the call to `Activate()` and it seems to be working more consistently now.